# Math-ish recursion to formula

Tags: math, recursion

Ok, 
so this is a application of existing mathematical practices, but I can't really apply them to my case.

So, I have `x` of a currency to increase the level of a game-object `y` for cost `z`.
`z` is calculated in `cost(y.lvl) = c_1 * c_2^y.lvl / c_3`, where the c's are constants.

I am seeking an efficient way to calculate, how often I can increase the level of `y`, given `x`. Currently I'm using a loop that does something like this:

```
double tempX = x;
int counter = 0;
while(tempX >= cost(y.lvl+counter)){
    tempX-=cost(y.lvl)+counter;
    counter++;
}
```

The problem is, that in some cases, this loop has to iterate too many times to stay performant.

What I am looking for is essentially a function
`int howManyCanBeBought(x,y.lvl)`, which calculates it's result in a single go, instead of looping a lot of times.

I've read something about transforming recursions to generating functions and transforming them to closed formulas, but I didn't get the math behind it. Is there an easy way to it?

Comment: look for the formulae for integrating an exponent

Comment: The integral of the cost function will give me values for "how expensive it would be to upgrade from alpha to beta" in one go, but while alpha=y.lvl, I would then again have to recursively find the biggest beta, for which the integral is <=x, right?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for the largest n such that:

Σ<sub>i=0..n</sub> c<sub>1</sub>/c<sub>3</sub> c<sub>2</sub><sup>lvl+i</sup> ≤ x

Dividing by the constant factor:

Σ<sub>i=0..n</sub> c<sub>2</sub><sup>i</sup> ≤ c<sub>3</sub> / (c<sub>1</sub> c<sub>2</sub><sup>lvl</sup>) x

Using the formula for the sum of a geometric series:

(c<sub>2</sub><sup>n+1</sup> - 1) / (c<sub>2</sub> - 1) ≤ c<sub>3</sub> / (c<sub>1</sub> c<sub>2</sub><sup>lvl</sup>) x

And solving for the maximum integer:

n = floor(log<sub>c<sub>2</sub></sub>(c<sub>3</sub> (c<sub>2</sub> - 1) / (c<sub>1</sub> c<sub>2</sub><sup>lvl</sup>) x + 1) - 1)

Comment: Looks promising. I'll have an exact look at it tomorrow.

Comment: Sure. In case you meant c_2^(y.lvl / c_3) -- that could be solved by replacing c_2 with (c_2^(1/c_3)).

Comment: I meant the upper version and it seems to be right, thanks! For some reason however, it can go result in n=-1, which shouldn't happen obviously, so I just removed the -1 at the end and it seems to work fine. :)

Comment: Looks like I understood it less than I expected. I changed the above formulae to cost(y.lvl) = c_1 * ((c_4*y.lvl)+1)* c_2^y.lvl / c_3, but now I can't just use the geometric series and do the same thing, or can I?

Comment: Now you have an `i c^i` term, so [another formula](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+i+*+c%5Ei+for+i+%3D+0..n) is necessary. Summing the costs gives [the following](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+c_1+(c_4+i+%2B+1)+c_2%5E(i%2Bl)+%2F+c_3+for+i+%3D+0..n) (where `l` is the starting level), which you would have to solve for `n`.